# Regex INSTR -Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a question related to a snowflake query:

Oracle query:

```
INSTR(CFileName, '/', -1) + 1)
```

Snowflake query

```
regexp_instr(CFileName, '/', -1) + 1
```

But when I run this in the Snowflake environment, I get this error:

> Invalid parameter value: -3. Reason: Position must be positive

Can you please tell me how to read this below code? And how the output logic?

```
select regexp_instr('ygzff/afzfzh/yfzdaf/yftfrxdff/aa/ff', '/',3)+1
```

The answer for above is 7 in snowflake. how sf calculate the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select 
    'ygzff/afzfzh/yfzdaf/yftfrxdff/aa/ff' as input,
    regexp_instr(input, '/',1) as r1,
    regexp_instr(input, '/',2) as r2,
    regexp_instr(input, '/',3) as r3,
    r3+1;
```

gives:

| INPUT | R1 | R2 | R3 | R3+1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ygzff/afzfzh/yfzdaf/yftfrxdff/aa/ff | 6 | 6 | 6 | 7 |

the 1,2,3 in my example are the start offset, and result is 1 based offset the `/` which is the 6. thus the answer 7

The Oracle [INSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions068.htm) position -1 is saying count from the end, and thus is returning the position after the last instance of '/'

we can flip the string around, to find the tail, then minus if the token was found, and then use that like:

```
select 
    'ygzff/afzfzh/yfzdaf/yftfrxdff/aa/ff' as input,
    length(input) as l,
    regexp_instr(reverse(input), '/') as r,
    iff(r=0,0,l-(r-2)) as tp,
    substr(input, tp) as tail;
```

| INPUT | L | R | TP | TAIL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ygzff/afzfzh/yfzdaf/yftfrxdff/aa/ff | 35 | 3 | 34 | ff |

or you can also use [RIGHT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/right.html)

```
select 
    column1 as input,
    length(input) as l,
    regexp_instr(reverse(input), '/') as r,
    right(input, iff(r=0,l,r-1))
from values 
    ('ygzff/afzfzh/yfzdaf/yftfrxdff/aa/ff'),
    ('no slashes here');
```

| INPUT | L | R | RIGHT(INPUT, IFF(R=0,L,R-1)) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ygzff/afzfzh/yfzdaf/yftfrxdff/aa/ff | 35 | 3 | ff |
| no slashes here | 15 | 0 | no slashes here |